# Function address nearly the same as other variables addresses

Tags: c

Why are function addresses nearly the same as the address of static global variables or dynamically allocated variables? Here is the code for demonstration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int global_var;
int global_var1;
int global_var2;

static int st_var = 3;

void func()
{
  return;
}

int main(void)
{ 
  int x;
  int* x_m = malloc(sizeof(int));
  printf("Malloc: %p\n", x_m);

  printf("Local: %p\n", &x);

  printf("Function: %p\n", &func);

  printf("Global: %p\n", &global_var);
  printf("Global: %p\n", &global_var1);
  printf("Global: %p\n", &global_var2);

  printf("Static: %p\n", &st_var);


  free(x_m);
  return 0;
}
```

```
Output: 
Malloc: 0x55bede9ce2a0
Local: 0x7ffdbc67b25c
Function: 0x55bede7151a9
Global: 0x55bede718024
Global: 0x55bede718030
Global: 0x55bede718020
Static: 0x55bede718010
```

Can somebody explain this? Because I thought that just global and static variables are stored into the `.bss` segment.

Comment: Can you run the program multiple times and see if you get the same behavior, i think its just random

Comment: I have done this, they are always nearly the same as the function address!

Comment: Your function and global variable addresses are nearly 12,000 apart - is that *really* "nearly the same"?

Comment: in the dupe you have the way to check the location of the object runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because, usually, the `.text` section (containing function code) and the `.bss` section of an ELF executable are mapped "relatively near" each other.

You can check this with `readelf`:

```
$ gcc prog.c
$ readelf -S a.out
There are 29 section headers, starting at offset 0x1ac0:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
...
  [14] .text             PROGBITS         00000000000007e0  000007e0
       0000000000000302  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     16
...
  [24] .bss              NOBITS           0000000000201010  00001010
       0000000000000010  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
...
```

You can see from above from the "Address" field of `.text` and `.bss` that they will be loaded `0x201010-0x7e0 = 0x200830`  bytes apart in virtual memory when the program runs.

In any case, this does ***not*** mean that your code is in the `.bss` section or that your variables are in the `.text` section. They are in two different yet "relatively near" sections.

The distance between the two is arbitrary, there is no real minimum or maximum requirement dictated by the ELF specification. You could write your own [linker script](https://wiki.osdev.org/Linker_Scripts) to place them farther away if you really want.

Comment: They should at least be on different pages, which is sort of a "minimum" distance.  But it's true they could be close together on adjoining pages.

Comment: And I guess 2 GB is a maximum distance when using the default small code model.

Comment: @NateEldredge it's not required by the standard, they can very well be on the same page ([example](https://i.imgur.com/b55Rn3F.png)), though that would of course cause page permissions issues and no sane compiler would do that by default. In fact, it sometimes happens that sections spanning more than one page have the last page with permissions which are too permissive due to this.

Comment: But what's actually up with shared memory variables like one's with mmap? Are they eventually nearer to the text segment?

Comment: @greatgesture no, `mmap` is a completely different story.

Comment: Okey, what would you assume is the nearest to the function address on a typical memory layout and architecture? Global initialized variables?

Comment: @greatgesture I wouldn't assume anything, I would look into it with `readelf`. Please, don't mistake this comment section for a chat. If you have more questions, ask them with a new post.